# multiCapabilities function replacing the existing HTML report in execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I need to run my tests in chrome,FF and IE. When I use multiCapabilities function,it will execute the script and generate the HTML report in base location for first browser.When it goes to next browser execution,it will replace the existing execution report with the current execution report.What I need is I need to retain both the execution results.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}],
```

For first "Chrome" execution it wil generate the report at base location.When it move to "FF" execution,it will replace the existing "Chrome" report with the new "FF" report.Any suggestion to retain bothe the reports in base location?
Please do the needful.Waiting for the reply.

Comment: What package are you using for reporting? `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`?

Comment: @alecxe 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter' is the report currently I am using.

Comment: @alecxe hi..any update from your side?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add onPrepare function to export configs and create different save path for each browser:

```
onPrepare: function () {
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
                new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                    savePath: 'results/',
                    filePrefix: browserName + '-report',
                    takeScreenshots: true
                })
            );
        });
    }
```